# Alternative inputs to SciPy Radial Basis Functions

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to generate a radial basis function where the input variables are defined at runtime. The SciPy.interpolate.Rbf function seems to request discrete lists for each input and output variable, eg: rbf(x,y,z). This restricts you to defining fixed variables before hand.

I have tried unsuccessfully to pass a list or array of variables to the Rbf function (eg. rbf(list(x,...)) with no success. Has anyone else found a solution to this problem using this Rbf library? I would like to avoid switching to a different library or rewriting one if possible. Is there a way to generate discrete variables at runtime to feed into a function?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `args = [x, y, z, d]`, built at runtime, then do `rbfi = Rbf(*args)`.

Comment: Does the * enumerate the array into individual variables?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) for details.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the source for the SciPy function, I will just subclass it and override **init** where the individual inputs are combined into an array anyway.